# FireBase PhoneAuth Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I try to set PhoneAuth from firebase, but im new one and i just don't know why it happens

Here is that part of code

```
 let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: defaults.string(forKey: "AuthVID")!, verificationCode: self.codeInputField.text!)
```

[Here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eO3e.png)

[What Xcode shows about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxZXM.png)

i think problem is in here but i don't know how to solve it

```
Printing description of credential:(PhoneAuthCredential) credential = <variable not available>
```

Thank you

Comment: 'defaults.string(forKey: "AuthVID")!' please check if it is 'nil' don't unwrap forcefully

Comment: This error show that your assigned variable get a nil value. In let credential no value assigned. here you can give default value to assigned variable then print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem seem to have in the below line , because your are unwrapping  optional forcefully .

```
let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: defaults.string(forKey: "AuthVID")!, verificationCode: self.codeInputField.text!)
```

**Reason**

May be your `AuthVID` is nil , (there is no String in `UserDefuilt` with key AuthID ) or  `self.codeInputField` is not connected to `outlet`

**Solution**

Either provide default value  or use optional chaining .

```
if let strAuthVID = defaults.string(forKey: "AuthVID"), let code = self.codeInputField.text
{
let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID:strAuthVID, verificationCode: code)

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply
I did as you said and this if statement doesn't hold.

Comment: Nothing, i don't get any error. So i added else statement like 
`if let strAuthVID = defaults.string(forKey: "AuthVID"), let code = self.codeInputField.text
{
let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID:strAuthVID, verificationCode: code)

} else {
print("Doesn't work")
}`
And when im clicking on button, its printing "Doesn't work"

Comment: Yes Because you are Getting `nil` value , it may be `strAuthVID` or `code` debug and than find out which one is `nil` . please see the answer the possible reason i have written .

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll found out where and why im getting nil value

Comment: The solution was pretty easy :D I just had a mistake in name for key "authVID" in other viewController. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know how the heck did I got the same mistake. But after wasting so much time, I found your answer. Thanks a ton!!